# Delphi XE2: «Лишние» строки в исполняемом файле

Tags: delphi, exe, delphi-xe2, executable

Скомпилировал программу в режиме Release. Вся отладочная информация при компиляции отключена.
Запустил программу, открыл ее свойства в [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
На закладке Strings вижу, что Process Explorer нашел много строк, которые являются названиями модулей Delphi, названиями классов, названиями процедур и функций.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно удалить из релизного exe-шника все лишние данные???

Comment: А еще можно прогнать ехе через упаковщик, типа upx.exe и сократить размер почти вдвое.

Comment: @KromStern антивирусы очень не любят такие упаковщики и часто только из-за них возникают ложные срабатывания антивируса.

Answer (score 6):

1) В `dpr` файле между ключевым словом `program` и разделом `uses` напишите:

```
program XXX;

{$WEAKLINKRTTI ON}        // если вам не нужны новые возможности RTTI!
{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([]) FIELDS([]) PROPERTIES([])}    // если вам не нужны новые возможности RTTI!

uses
...
```

2) В `dpr` файле после раздела `uses` можно еще добавить:

```
{$IFNDEF DEBUG}
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED} // Удаление из exe таблицы релокаций.
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_DEBUG_STRIPPED} //  Удаление из ехе Debug информации
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED} // Удаление из exe информации о номерах строк
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED} // Удаление local symbols
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP} //При запуске exe с компакта, флэшки, других извлекаемых устройств, считать exe в свап и запустить оттуда. Полезно, если нужно запустить программу с компакта, а потом попросить вставить другой...
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP} // Аналогично предыдущей, только для сетевых дисков
{$ENDIF}
```

При этом в `uses` должен присутствовать модуль `Windows`.

Это значительно уменьшит размер исполняемого файла и уберет "лишнюю" информацию из него.

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаюсь, что эти данные лишние.

Delphi при сборке обычно прикомпилирует некоторые "свои" модули к программе. Это можно отключить в настройках компилятора. Но, тогда придётся **всегда** "таскать" с программой все необходимые компоненты в виде .bpl включая те же кнопки и т.д. (смотря какие модули отключите)

Вообще, релиз - это максимум что может дать компилятор.
Большей экономии размера можно достичь, например, как уже говорилось, вынеся всё из экзешника ("таская" .bpl) или отказавшись от VCL (FireMonkey) в пользу чистого WinAPI (если это действительно оправдано).

Comment: Релиз - это еще не все что может дать компилятор. Насчет `bpl` все верно.