# FreePascal - скрыть имена классов в бинарном файле после компиляции

Tags: freepascal

Инструмент: Lazarus IDE + FPC 3.1.1.

Суть: В коде имеются классы вида TMyObject. При компиляции кода в бинарном файле создаются строковые имена этих классов.

Можно ли как-то компилятору запретить формировать эти строки? Скрыть названия классов из бинарного файла, или возможно видоизменить/обфусцировать.

Comment: Давно не брал Лазарус в руки, может быть что-нибудь из ответов на этот вопрос пригодится - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456393

Comment: @KromStern, увы эти способы не подходят для моего случая, и вероятно для самого типа проблемы. Там указаны способы для Windows исполняемых файлов. Я собираю библиотеки под UNIX систему, в частности Android, и хотелось бы чтобы FPC исключал названия моих классов из бинарника (пускай свои библиотеки тянет как хочет, но не мои модули).

Comment: То есть в общем случае вас интересует обфускация имен классов. Возможно какие-то сторонние утилиты могут это сделать.

Comment: @KromStern, в общем хотелось бы, чтобы не было вообще никаких связей класса с любыми строками, ну а в частном случае подойдет и обфускация. Я к сожалению не смог найти достойных инструментов для работы с unix бинарниками, которые бы усложняли отладку приложения, ну а так же поддерживали Android системы разных версий.